# Switching between Chrome browser windows

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, gesture, hotkeys

I want to create a gesture for [StrokesPlus](http://www.strokesplus.com/) that will switch between the Google Chrome windows. Of course it is possible to switch with Alt + Tab, but I don't want to see other programs that are running.

It seems like in Mac OS there exists cmd + backtick shortcut for this. But I couldn't find Windows equivalent shortcut for switching.

Comment: I wish Apple would fix this some day.

Answer (score 71):

The shortcut **Command + `** (the key just above the tab key on your keyboard) is the standard Mac OS shortcut for switching between the windows in the currently selected application, and works in Chrome.

Comment: There is a difference. In Mac it doesn't switches between recent chrome windows...Instead it cycles through all the opened chrome windows. which is very annoying.

Comment: it is outdated, `command + \`` reverse cycle of recently open apps

Answer (score 24):

Looks like the old COMMAND + ` combo no longer works.

Try `control` + `left/right arrow` instead.
Worked on my m1 Macbook pro running macOS Big Sur.

Comment: I could confirm this works on MBP 16 2019 running latest macOS Big Sur.

Comment: On MacOS, Command + <backtick/tilde> still works (at least on Mojave), but if one of your Chrome windows is in Full Screen mode (or even if you just have a tab with a full screen Youtube video) then you need to use Control + <left/right arrow> to cycle between windows.

Comment: ⌘` doesn't work for my Macbook with MacOS Big Sur and Google Chrome 94.

Comment: left right depends on sequence or order of opening windows (all apps confused)

Comment: I could confirm this works in macOS Monterey and It toggles between all open windows

Comment: This shortcut is for switching between desktops, not application windows. It works only if each application windows is in full screen, and therefore fills a desktop.

Comment: Praise God! Of all the wrong `CMD + `` answers that doesn't work on a new MacBook Air, this was the correct solution.

Answer (score 12):

If Chrome is on the first place (leftmost) on your taskbar, press "`Win + 1`" TWICE to switch to the second window, working exactly like "`Cmd + tilde`" on Mac; press them ONCE to switch back.

If your Chrome is on the second place, press "`Win + 2`" TWICE to switch;

and so on.

Comment: :o this is amazing!

Comment: On windows 10, Win + 2 opens a new chrome instance instead of navigating between chrome instances.
Other apps Win + taskBarID works fine though the problem is only with chrome

Answer (score 9):

Do `Cmd` + `Tab`, select the application (chrome in this case) , then use the down arrow and all windows of the same application will appear, select the window using left and right key and hit `return` .

Comment: I only see chrome. not two windows of chrome

Comment: Who invented this.... it's more convenient to use the mouse than this.

Answer (score 6):

> It seems like in Mac OS there exists cmd + backtick shortcut for this. But I couldn't find Windows equivalent shortcut for switching.

**Mac OS**: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> (i.e. *Command* key + *Single Quote* key).

**PC / Windows**: Depends on which order of your launched programme, i.e. if your Chrome was the first programme launched, then press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for switching between Chrome windows. Provided if you have *Windows Key* on your keyboard.

- *<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Number #</kbd> opens the desktop and start the app pinned to the taskbar in the position indicated by the number. Keep pressing the "key combination" would switch between within selected app group.*

> I want to create a gesture for StrokesPlus that will switch between the Google Chrome windows.

That's handy too.

Answer (score 2):

check System **Preference - Keyboard - Shortcuts - Keyboard.**

Although my shortcut is already set cmd + ` to switch windows, it doesn't work on Google Chrome.
I just figured out that with **Cmd + Number#** I can switch to another windows. But it's not that handy when you have many windows on Chrome.

Comment: This switches only between tabs, not between windows

Answer (score 0):

By pressing CTRL+TAB you can switch between windows in Windows. This is the desired behaviour, at least the one I am looking for (to be able to do the same with Cmd+TAB in MacOS).

Is there any advance or workaround with this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me: swiping down on the trackpad with 3 fingers to see all windows then select the wanted chrome window. It's show all windows of all applications, so maybe not the best but an alternative option...